# How to output JSON structure into tag's data attribute

Tags: phoenix-framework

I'm having trouble escaping json string. Basically I want to end up with `<div id="something" data-points='[{"a":1}, {"b":2}]'>`

So in my template I have something like

`#map(data-markers: "#{waypoints_to_json(@waypoints)}")

And the view:

`defmodule PedalApp.Web.MapHelper do
  def waypoints_to_json(waypoints) do
    Poison.encode!(waypoints) |> Phoenix.HTML.raw
  end
end`

Problem is that it doesn't escape quotes, so it wrecks html.

What's the proper way to cram json into a data attribute?

Comment: What templating engine are you using?

Comment: Don't use `|> Phoenix.HTML.raw`. Just do `#map(data-markers: "#{Poison.encode!(@waypoints)}")`.

Comment: @Dogbert oh man, that works. I thought that html looked suspicious. Thanks.

Comment: @NavinPeiris https://github.com/chrismccord/phoenix_haml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work if you remove the call to `Phoenix.HTML.raw` and let the template engine handle escaping. The generated HTML might contain `&quot;` instead of `"`, like this:

```
<div data-points="[&quot;foo&quot;]"></div>
```

but that is correct and if you try to access that property using JS, you'll get back the correct unescaped form.

```js
alert(document.querySelector("div").getAttribute("data-points"));
```

```html
<div data-points="[&quot;foo&quot;, &quot;bar&quot;]"></div>
```